# Restructure CSV file with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Date     Name    Wage
5/1/19   Joe     $100
5/1/19   Sam     $120
5/1/19   Kate    $30
5/2/19   Joe     $120
5/2/19   Sam     $134
5/2/19   Kate    $56
5/3/19   Joe     $89
5/3/19   Sam     $90
5/3/19   Kate    $231
```

I would like to restructure it to look like this:

```
Date      Joe    Sam    Kate
5/1/19    $100   $120   $30
5/2/19    $120   $134   $56
5/3/19    $89    $90    $231
```

I am not sure how to approach it.
Here is what I started writing:

```
import csv

with open ('myfile.csv', 'rb') as filein, open ('restructured.csv', 'wb') as fileout:
  rows = list(csv.DictReader(filein, skipinitialspace=True))
  names = NOT SURE HOW TO GET THIS
  fieldnames = ['Date'] + ['{}'.format(i) for i in names]
  csvout = csv.DictWriter(fileout, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore', restval='NA')
  csvout.writeheader()
  for row in rows:
    row['{}'.format(row['Name'].strip())] = row['Wage']
    csvout.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The csv modules is just a parser that yields the CSV rows as tuples or dicts. It does not transform by itself the rows into something else.

Comment: it would be easier to use pandas in this case

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind pointing me at pandas example that does something similar?

Comment: @manticora This video could help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcqPhpY7tWk

Comment: What is the separator? Does `list(csv.DictReader(filein, skipinitialspace=True))` return what you expect?

Comment: @manticora Take a look at this link : https://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/

Comment: It sounds like you want to `transpose` a data frame: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Comment: Are you really using Python 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with the csv module. Here is the way for Python 3:

```
import csv
import collections

with open ('myfile.csv', 'r') as filein, open ('restructured.csv', 'w', newline='') as fileout:
    data = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    names = set()
    for row in csv.DictReader(filein, skipinitialspace=True):
        data[row['Date']][row['Name']] = row['Wage']
        names.add(row['Name'])
    csvout = csv.DictWriter(fileout, fieldnames = ['Date'] + list(names))
    csvout.writeheader()
    for dat in sorted(data.keys()):
        row = data[dat]
        row['Date'] = dat
        csvout.writerow(row)
```

The generated csv should look like:

```
Date,Kate,Joe,Sam
5/1/19,$30,$100,$120
5/2/19,$56,$120,$134
5/3/19,$231,$89,$90
```

It is the same for Python 2 except for the first line which should be:

```
with open ('myfile.csv', 'rb') as filein, open ('restructured.csv', 'wb') as fileout:
```

Comment: It did work for me - thank you very much! But the data is not sorted by date :( My first column looks like this:
 
Date
5/1/19
5/2/19
5/19/19
5/29/19
5/24/19
5/27/19
5/21/19
5/9/19

I tried sorting it with python afterwords, but got the following error: ValueError: time data '5' does not match format '%m-%d-%y'

Comment: It can easily be sorted by date. See my edit at `for dat in sorted(data.keys()):`

Comment: I think it doesn't recognize it as date because this time it sorted it this way: 5/1/19, 5/10/19, 5/11/19 and so on

Answer (score 2):

Simply with `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep="\s+")
p_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Wage', columns=['Name'], index='Date', 
                         aggfunc=lambda x:x)
p_table = p_table.reset_index()
p_table.columns.name = None

print(p_table)
```

The output:

```
     Date   Joe  Kate   Sam
0  5/1/19  $100   $30  $120
1  5/2/19  $120   $56  $134
2  5/3/19   $89  $231   $90
```

---

Reference links:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: I like your aggregating function here, I hadn't seen or thought of that before.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is also known as converting from long to wide format. Using `pandas` you can easily do this by

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep = ',')

# Restructure the dataframe
tdf = df.pivot(index = 'Date', columns = 'Name', values = 'Wage')

tdf.to_csv("restructured.csv", sep = ',')

print(tdf)
Name     Joe  Kate   Sam
Date                    
5/1/19  $100   $30  $120
5/2/19  $120   $56  $134
5/3/19   $89  $231   $90
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right track

data.csv

```
5/1/19,Joe,$100
5/1/19,Sam,$120
5/1/19,Kate,$30
5/2/19,Joe,$120
5/2/19,Sam,$134
5/2/19,Kate,$56
5/3/19,Joe,$89
5/3/19,Sam,$90
5/3/19,Kate,$231
```

```
data = {}
people = set()
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        values = line.split(',')

        if values[0] not in data:
            data[values[0]] = {}

        data[values[0]][values[1]] = values[2]
        people.add(values[1])

print('Date,' + ','.join([per for per in people]))
for date in data:
    print(f"{date},{','.join([data[date][per] for per in people])}"
```

output:

```
Date,Sam,Kate,Joe
5/1/19,$120,$30,$100
5/2/19,$134,$56,$120
5/3/19,$90,$231,$89
```

Comment: I think OP wants to save as a CSV file, not print the outputs.